# Android Studio Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes defaults to smallest image

Tags: android, dpi

I am trying to support all screen sizes. I have followed many tutorials and this is what I have.

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens= "true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />
```

Has been added to android manifest

I've imported the 9 patch files that were created using Android's Online Tool

[image: Res Layouts]

But on all devices it seems to still default to the smallest picture. Here is a screenshot of the HTC One Maxx (5.9 inch screen)

[image: Mobile Screen]

Android Layout for the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/account_button_pressed"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/account_button_focused"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/account_button_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

Android screen layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/directmessage_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_DirectMessages"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/instantmessage_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_InstantMessage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_DirectMessages"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/reports_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_Reports"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_DirectMessages"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/conference_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_Conference"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Reports"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_DirectMessages"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/account_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_Account"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Reports"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="20px"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/filetransfer_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_FileTransfer"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_Conference"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Account"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="20px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```